# How to profile laravel's REST API

Tags: api, rest, laravel, profiling

There's a great extension to laravel: debugbar.
But what if I have an REST API. With like no frontend.
How do I profile this type of application?

Comment: There are great browser extensions to test REST APIs. For example [Advanced REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) for Chrome.

Comment: I'm using a Postman.app. But it's not about testing APIs. It's about profiling.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of returning your response, send it to a view:

```
return \View::make('debug', ['data' => $response]);
```

instead of

```
//return response()->json($response);
```

(don't forget to create the view where you echo your data)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this Middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;

class ProfileJsonResponse
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        if (
            $response instanceof JsonResponse &&
            app()->bound('debugbar') &&
            app('debugbar')->isEnabled() &&
            is_object($response->getData())
        ) {
            $response->setData($response->getData(true) + [
                '_debugbar' => app('debugbar')->getData(),
            ]);
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Reference https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/issues/252

Comment: He's the same who posted this issue :D